# Justify-Content style of Flexbox inside of another Flexbox is not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

I have a **flexbox inside another flexbox** with a style of **justify-content set to space-between** but for some reason **the style is not applying** and the children elements remain bunched up next to each other.

```css
#nav {
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  height: 70%;
}

#nav-links {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="get-started-nav">
  <svg id="logo"></svg>
  <div id="nav-links">
    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried removing the "position: absolute;" style, removing flexbox and align items styles from parent element and these haven't done anything. There is also plenty of room for the flexbox to expand but it is not. I would appreciate any help on this as I just cannot see the error in my code.

Comment: You'd make things a lot easier if you'd give us HTML instead of JSX here. It's apparently just a CSS question, so why tangle React and routing into the question? Put it all in a demo snippet using the editor.

Comment: @isherwood It was simply incase there was some sort of effect that having the code in react was having as there are a few small differences in html and react

Comment: No there aren't. React _compiles_ HTML, and HTML is what the browser sees. It's also what CSS acts on.

Comment: I meant simple syntax differences like "ClassName" and "class" and thought potentially there could be a subtle error in my syntax when targeting the elements for styling

Comment: Fair enough, but as you can see by the lack of helpful responses your question is difficult to diagnose. If you do what I ask you may spot the problem yourself or we may. You can then apply the solution to your React code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add some     `width`    or     `flex-grow:1`    in    `#nav-link`     . If you are adding flex-grow then you must add     `flex-shrink:0`    in    `Logo`    .